# I hereby nominate dickchop as Answer of the Year

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/posts/165976/revisions

I just love the fact that he went in and edited his answer to change `hanging` to `hangin`, but still used the term `math's` instead of `dem number thingos`. Aaah to have that youthful spirit.

Comment: I saw that answer go by and just shook my head. Kids these days.

Comment: Minor note: "math's" was intended by the author as a contraction of "math is" rather than the British "maths" with an extraneous apostrophe.

Comment: @Dennis, that makes it even worse, it means that he was gramatically CORRECT!

Comment: Also nominated for nickname of the year....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Imma let you finish, but dickchop had one of the best answers of all time.

Comment: Ahhhh this will never get old, will it?

Comment: So how's that translate in Italian? :)

Answer (score 3):

Wow.  Just...wow.